# Make sure the string from the instruction is exactly what you are returning

Tags: python

Write a function called "show_excitement" where the string

"I am super excited for this course!" is returned exactly

5 times, where each sentence is separated by a single space.

Return the string with "return".

You can only have the string once in your code.

Don't just copy/paste it 5 times into a single variable!

```
    def show_excitement():
    # Your code goes here!
    for i in range(1, 6):
        print ("I am super excited for this course! ")
    return " "

print show_excitement()
```

> How to solve this please help

Comment: Your function (once you've fixed the indentation) will **not** return anything other than a string comprised of a single space. Also, your syntax for *print* is invalid

Comment: Please go through this once. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
def show_excitement():
    return ' '.join(["I am super excited for this course!"] * 5)

print(show_excitement())

# I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course!
```

You were almost there.

1. You printed the sentence five times *inside* your function, but the instruction requires that you return a string (without printing inside the function). So use `return` followed by a string.
2. The correct syntax for `print` is `print(...)`, not `print ...`.
3. Putting a space between sentences is not quite clean with a `for` loop, because you need to take care of a trailing space (or leading space).

   For example,

   `"I am super excited for this course! " * 5`

   would result in

   `"I am super excited for this course! ... I am super excited for this course! "`

   (Note the final blank in the string.)

   Here I used `join` to insert spaces between five sentences. If the instructor wants you to learn `for` loop specifically, then you can try:

   ```py
   def show_excitement():
       s = ""
       for i in range(5):
           if i > 0:
               s += ' '
           s += "I am super excited for this course!"
       return s
   ```

Comment: Thanks and I have one more solution but your answer is just awesome..                           var = "I am super excited for this course!"
var = var.replace('!', '! ')
return(var*5)

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```py
def show_excitement():
    return "I am super excited for this course! " * 5

print(show_excitement())
```

Comment: read the question we need to give space '  ' between them, so I just used '.join'

Comment: @suraj_0o0 Its there after `course!` word !!

Comment: I also used the same trick! and got 'error'  the question is "each sentence is separated by a single space."

Answer (score 0):

try this. hope this is what you expected. resulting print(word,word,word,word,word). can be achieve by followed

```
def show_excitement():
        return ("I am super excited for this course! \n")*5
print (show_excitement())
```

or

```
def show_excitement():
        return ["I am super excited for this course!" for i in range(1, 6)]
print (show_excitement())
```

Comment: we need to print it without using the function, I mean by using str so for loop can't be used either we can just return the function because it's mentation in the question that every sentence needs a space between them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def show_excitement(test):

    for i in range(1, 6):
        print (test)



show_excitement("I am super excited for this course! ")
```

The beauty and purpose of the function is now that you can use it with anything you would like to say.....

like:

```
show_excitement("I am superman, actually! ")
```

Comment: this is just an awesome answer but, we need to give space and while that we should not use the function, we have to use Str.